# Verificar se um option já existe pra não repeti-lo

Tags: php, javascript

Olá!

Tenho um problema talvez simples, mas não tô conseguindo pensar em qualquer maneira de resolvê-lo.

Tenho um banco de dados aonde tenho uma tabela de produtos nele. Nessa tabela, tem a coluna `cor`. Então, estou criando um filtro na hora de pesquisar os produtos no site e como não sei exatamente quais cores estão em estoque, fiz esse while para imprimir as options:

```
$sql =  "SELECT `cor` FROM `produtos`";
<select id='iCor' name='nCor'>
       <option value=''>Todos</option>";
       while($linha = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $cor = $linha['cor'];
            echo"<option value='$cor'>$cor</option>";
       }`
```

Mas esse com essa forma se eu tenho registrado as seguintes cores: `amarelo`, `verde`, `vermelho`, `amarelo`, vai aparecer 2 `options` contendo a opção `amarelo`.

O que eu quero é que de alguma forma, seja verificado se já tem aquele `option` no `select`. Se tiver, não faz nada. Se não tiver, coloca a cor como novo `option`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta usar essa consulta:

```
$sql =  "SELECT DISTINCT `cor` FROM `produtos`";
```

Comment: Não sei porque recebeu um -1, funcionou mesmo!